# How to use VL53L1X with FPGA devices

Tags: fpga

My school asked me to make a range finder by VL53L1X, with a Cyclone IV device to drive it.

But I found [Note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Eqj.png) in its manual, warning customers to use VL53L1X software driver.
Noticing that full register details are not exposed, which means I cannot communicate with VL53L1X just by building an I2C driver by myself with FPGA.

So I wonder is there any way to drive VL53L1X with FPGA devices, I've searched for a long time but didn't get anything meaningful.

Comment: My teacher told me to read the C code published by ST, so I have to deal with these terrifying code. If I could finish this, I'll be glad to share the experience and my Verilog code at Github, perhaps.

Comment: I have finished this by using Nios II, after analyzing the code in GitHub, my team developed a brief version in C. And it works. I'll publish our code on GitHub when this school assignment finishes.